# Read a Person object from file stream

Tags: c++, beginner

A simple concept yet I seem to have written it in a complicated way.

I have written some C++ source code that should:

- read in a file
- parse it
- save the data to a class
- print out all the saved class data

I am absolutely new to C++ and OOP and Programming and English.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

class Person {
private:
    int age;
    std::string name;

public:
    void setAge(int age) {
        this->age = age;
    }

    int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    void setName(std::string name) {
        this->name = name;
    }

    std::string getName() {
        return name;
    }

    void printInfo() {
        std::cout
            << "Name: " << getName() << '\n'
            << "Age: " << getAge() << '\n';
    }
};

std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& is, Person& person) {
    int age;
    is >> age;

    std::string name;
    is >> name;

    person.setAge(age);
    person.setName(name);

    return is;
}

int main() {
    auto myfilename = "unknown-people.txt";

    std::ofstream myfile(myfilename, std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);
    myfile << "3 Baby\n";
    myfile << "48 Linus Torvalds\n";
    myfile << "62 Bill Gates\n";
    myfile << "115 Kane Tanaka\n";
    myfile.close();


    std::ifstream mysamefile(myfilename, std::ios::binary);

    std::string details;
    std::vector<Person> people;

    while (std::getline(mysamefile, details)) {
        Person person;
        std::istringstream personDetails(details);
        personDetails >> person;
        people.push_back(person);
    }

    mysamefile.close();


    for (std::vector<Person>::iterator it = people.begin(); it != people.end(); ++it) {
        it->printInfo();

        if (!(it != people.end() && it == --people.end())) {
            std::cout << "\n\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have a good grasp of the concepts - this is looking pretty good for a first effort!

Those accessors (`setAge()` + `getAge()`, and `setName()` + `getName()`) are exactly equivalent to making the members `age()` and `name()` public, which would be simpler and clearer.  I'll assume that you're later going to add some code to check that the values are reasonable (don't allow negative ages, for example, nor empty or whitespace-only names).

Note also that the "get" accessors can be marked `const`, because they don't change the `Person`:

```
int getAge() const {
    return age;
}

std::string getName() const {
    return name;
}
```

In passing, I'll note that storing age as a member might not be the best design, especially when storing to a file that might be read back several years later.  If we store the year of birth, that's something that won't normally change, and we can always calculate the age from it.

---

The `operator>>()` is mostly what I'd expect.  You can chain the reading like this:

```
int age;
std::string name;
is >> age >> name;
```

However, there's a bug here.  `is >> name` will read up to the next *whitespace*, but our names can have whitespace in them.  We actually want to read up to the next *newline*, like this:

```
std::string name;
std::getline(is, name);
```

Another consideration here is that we don't want to update the person if we failed to read both values (otherwise, `operator<<()` could be a `friend` function, and read directly to `person.age` and `person.name`).  We can easily test whether the reads succeeded:

```
if (is) {
    person.setAge(age);
    person.setName(name);
}
```

When we have a reader, it's a good idea to have a matching writer that produces the same format.  That's very simple to write:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Person& person) {
    return os << person.getAge() << ' '
              << person.getName() << '\n';
}
```

Note that we have a reference to a `const` person here - the writer is promising not to modify `person`.

---

When reading the people in, we don't need to copy each line of text into a buffer (once we've fixed the bug I mentioned with reading names) - we can stream directly from the file stream into the person object:

```
std::vector<Person> people;

Person person;
while (mysamefile >> person) {
    people.push_back(std::move(person));
}
```

(The `std::move()` is a non-essential optimisation - it says we won't be using `person` until it's re-written using `>>`).

---

When displaying the people, we can make the code simpler using range-based `for` like this:

```
for (const Person& person: people) {
    person.printInfo();
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}
```

Of course, this is slightly different, because we're now printing the newlines after the last person too.  A good way to solve this is to print the newlines *before* each person, but not if it's the first person.  To do this, we can initially set our separator to be an empty string, and update after it's used:

```
auto separator = "";
for (const Person& person: people) {
    std::cout << separator;
    separator = "\n\n";

    person.printInfo();
}
```

A nice touch would be to allow printing to somewhere other than `std::cout`, by passing the stream as an argument to `printInfo()`:

```
void printInfo(std::ostream& out = std::cout) const {
    out << "Name: " << name << '\n'
        << "Age: " << age << '\n';
}
```

---

## Modified code

I've rearranged the headers a bit, to ease the process for when you want to separate the class definition from the test program.  I've changed the file read/write to work purely in memory for the test (I don't like tests that leave files lying about; using real files also increases fragility of the tests).  And I've added some validation of ages and names.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

class Person
{
private:
    int age;
    std::string name;

public:
    void setAge(int age) {
        if (age < 0) {
            throw std::range_error("Negative age");
        }
        this->age = age;
    }

    int getAge() const {
        return age;
    }

    void setName(std::string name) {
        auto first_nonspace
            = std::find_if_not(name.begin(), name.end(),
                               [](unsigned char c){ return std::isspace(c); });
        if (first_nonspace == name.end()) {
            throw std::range_error("Invalid name");
        }
        this->name = name;
    }

    std::string getName() const {
        return name;
    }

    void printInfo(std::ostream& out) const {
        out << "Name: " << name << '\n'
            << "Age: " << age << '\n';
    }
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Person& person)
{
    int age;
    is >> age;

    std::string name;
    std::getline(is, name);

    if (is) {
        person.setAge(age);
        person.setName(name);
    }

    return is;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Person& person)
{
    return os << person.getAge() << ' '
              << person.getName() << '\n';
}


#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream myfile;
    myfile << "3 Baby\n";
    myfile << "48 Linus Torvalds\n";
    myfile << "62 Bill Gates\n";
    myfile << "115 Kane Tanaka\n";

    std::istringstream mysamefile(myfile.str());

    std::vector<Person> people;
    Person person;
    while (mysamefile >> person) {
        people.push_back(std::move(person));
    }

    auto separator = "";
    for (const Person& person: people) {
        std::cout << separator;
        separator = "\n\n";

        person.printInfo(std::cout);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd actually swap the output iterator and the `printInfo` operations and then replace the second half of main with these two statements: `std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Person>(mysamefile), std::istream_iterator<Person>(), std::back_inserter(people));
    std::copy(people.begin(), people.end(), std::experimental::make_ostream_joiner(std::cout, "\n\n"));`

Comment: Another possibility is to add a `static` member to `Person` to control which kind of output function (e.g. "plain" or "fancy") will be used and have the `ostream& operator>>` function call a public member function of `Person` to print.

Comment: `istream_iterator` makes sense - I completely overlooked that.  Not so sure about static member to change the printing - that really wouldn't work in a more complex (multithreaded) program.  I'd prefer a stream wrapper for that.

Comment: True, a stream wrapper would be much better than static member to control output.  Another approach (and the one I actually use most often) is just to select one "flavor" or another at compile-time.  Good review, BTW!

Comment: @Edward: if you want to control how the output is printed, I think the right way is probably a stream manipulator.

Comment: 1. Is no space after `operator>>` just stylistic (in `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Person& person)`)? I did a quick search and the majority do not have space after.

Comment: 2. How does line 53 (`if (istream) { /**/ }`) work? I thought it is a reference to `istream` and is always true?

Comment: 3. `std::getline(istream, name);` (line 51) reads an extra space into `name`. Is there a better way than using `get()` on `istream` and ignoring the space?

Comment: Your `separator` part is genius!

Comment: **1**. Yes, just a style choice (and consistent with other function definitions.  **2**. A reference isn't a pointer!  `std::istream` has [an `operator bool()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) which returns true if there's been no errors. **3**. I hadn't spotted that.  You could consume the space like this:  `int age; char space; is >> age >> space;`  It's up to you whether you actually check `std::isspace(space)` or not.

Comment: I find your use of get/setter disturbing. Especially in the context of a person. You see a use case for `p.setAge(p.getAge() + 4);` To me this breaks encapsulation by exposing the internals of the class. Much more logical to have `p.happyBirthday()` method to increase age (or maybe just store the birthdate (no need to ever change that after it has been set). Then make the input/output operators friends (thus exposing the actual tight coupling of these methods).

Comment: Er, no - I specifically recommend storing birthdate rather than age (fourth paragraph).

Answer (score 3):

#### What to Store

First of all, I'd advise against (ever) storing an age if you can help it. By *strong* preference, I would store something like a birthday instead of an age. Once a person is born, their birthday remains the same forever<sup>1</sup>. Depending on what sort of "age" you're dealing with, the relevant data might be when something was manufactured, harvested, collected, or something else, but the basic idea remains the same--if at all possible, record the starting time from which you an compute the age, rather than recording the age itself.

#### Pseudo-classes and Quasi-classes

[Warning: heretical statements ahead]

There's an old (by now probably even qualifies as ancient) [paper about pseudo-classes and quasi-classes](http://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf). Far too few have read or understood what it has to say, and the result is a lot of problematic code.

It's far better to read the paper than just my short summary, but your `Person` is nearly a textbook example of a quasi-class. You have a class with two data members, and each data member has an accessor and a mutator--each of which does *nothing* other than pass a value though from the inside to the outside or vice versa.

What you have is really a simple struct with effectively public data, but ugly, unreadable syntax to use it. Based on what you've shown so far, you'd be better off just writing:

```
struct Person {
    int age;
    std::string name;

    void printInfo() // ...
};
```

Some will certainly tell you that public data is always evil. You never know when you might need to represent a person's name in Sanskrit and modify your accessor to do an on-the-fly translation from Sanskrit by English by way of Swahili.

This sort of nonsense is what prompted the phrase "You ain't gonna need it" (and variations thereof). The fact is, lots of people write lots of code that throws away readability in favor of some long-term possibility that there's no particularly good reason to believe is ever likely to materialize.

Yes, it's possible that some day you may need to make changes. It has happened before, and it'll happen again. But experience tends to indicate that the changes we plan for and the changes that happen aren't always the same--and aren't the same even often enough to justify most of the attempts at planning ahead that people make either.

---

1. Of course, that doesn't mean their birthday can't ever be edited, such as to correct an error, but even that's fairly rare.

Comment: Did you mean "pass a value th**r**ough from the inside"?